# Emacs term и midnight commander

Tags: shell, emacs, manjaro, mc

Хочу сделать emacs term основным терминалом. При запуске mc (это запуск через `emacs -q`) получается вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Google молчит или я не правильно спрашиваю. В xfce4-terminal всё ок. И там и там шрифт одинаковый. Под убунтой было ок. Сейчас manjaro xfce. В чём может быть проблема и как это можно исправить?

Update

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (interactive)
                            (toggle-truncate-lines 1)))
```

Строки не переносятся, содержимое не помещается в окно и отсекаются последние строки. Может есть лучшее решение?

Comment: Вместо mc в emacs есть родные dired и tramp

Answer (score 1):

`term` плохо поддерживает *mc*. попробуйте `ansi-term` для полной эмуляции терминала.

Comment: Не. Тоже самое. В добавок обнаружил что мышка и функциональные клавиши тоже не работают. На полноценную замену специализированного эмулятора emacs, к сожалению,  еще не годится.

Comment: У меня с переносами все нормально, если не изменять размер окна (GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit) of 2018-03-08). Мышка и функциональные клавиши действительно не работают по умолчанию, но функциональные клавиши можно передать используя ESC+num. Это значит, что на реальные функциональные клавиши существует возможность забиндить нужное действие (смотри `term-send-raw-meta`).